# div reload with jquery and struts

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I would like to reload a div in a embedded tag inside my main app page template

Can I use JQuery for this ?

I am facing 2 issues :

my first problem I could solve with the following :
location.reload();
but this reloads everything ...
I am searching if I can reload only one div ( belonging to another page imported )

my second problem is the following :
I can´t trigger this function on my struts/jquery sj:a onclick
this href is inside a form and if I add this to my href ... it executes the function .. but doesn´t submit to the form´s action

So I need to :
1. what would be a way to trigger this function without jeopardizing my action submission
2. I would like to have the same behavior from location.relod() but for a div containing a struts url import to a jsp

Thks !!
Érico

Answer (score 1):

**Reloading a div without reloading whole page using jquery**

```
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
```